# NodeORM Group by Date Month

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm

So I'm using NodeORM and I want to get the sum of my records grouped by Month.

Example:

```
{ Month : 'January', sum: 50 },
{ Month : 'February', sum: -302 }
etc...
```

I know about the MONTH() function in MySQL but I really want to use my ORM Aggregations to make this one working.